# What's the difference between Gibbs Energy and Work?

Tags: thermodynamics

Gibbs energy is usually defined as the maximum useful work that a system can do on its surroundings. So what's the main difference between Gibbs energy and work?

Comment: Hey, if you do a search on chem.SE, you will see many other people have wondered about this before. See for example http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/32873/16683 (there are more).