# Gibbs Free energy Process v/s Reaction

Tags: thermodynamics, free-energy

How is Gibbs free energy for a reaction different from that in a process? Is it because a reaction generally occurs at a constant temperature and pressure, and so dG = dH - TdS, while for a process temperature may or may not be fixed for a process, say expansion of a gas, and so dG = dH - TdS - SdT? 
Also, how do we define H at non-constant pressure? Is it dH = dU + d(PV)?

Also, why do we say that The G at any point is the max non-mechanical work that can be drawn out? Why does this not include mechanical work too?

Comment: The second part has been addressed multiple times already - just a search for "gibbs work" will bring up several questions asking the same thing. http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32873/regarding-gibbss-function-why-is-there-non-expansion-work

Comment: We look at dG at constant temperature and pressure only as a vehicle for determining the relationship we need to use to calculate the equilibrium constant for the reaction.  That relationship can be used for all temperatures and pressures.