# Why in thermodynamics, some reactions are taken at constant temperature and pressure? What is its significance?

Tags: thermodynamics

To be more specific while deriving relation between cell emf and free energy, constant temperature and pressure  assumptions were taken. Why?

Answer (score 3):

If you read my answer to this question: [Why does the Gibbs free energy only correspond to non-expansion work?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32873/regarding-gibbss-function-why-is-there-non-expansion-work/32888#32888), you will see that

$$\mathrm{d}G = V\,\mathrm{d}p - S\,\mathrm{d}T + đW_\text{add}$$

Of these three terms, only $đW_\text{add}$ is related to the electrochemical work. Therefore, in order to equate $\mathrm{d}G$ to $đW_\text{add}$, you have to assume constant $p$ and $T$ such that both $\mathrm{d}p$ and $\mathrm{d}T$ are equal to 0.

In general, this applies to chemical equilibria as well. Because of the above expression, we can say that $G$ is the "natural quantity" to use in systems with fixed pressure and temperature. If instead you had a system with fixed volume and temperature, the [Helmholtz free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_free_energy) would become much more relevant.

Comment: That being said, I'd add that fixed volume requires some sophisticated experimental setup, while fixed pressure comes for free.